# Using jsPDF with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, jspdf

I'm trying to create generate a pdf document in my Electron application. When the user selects a JSON file I want to parse it and create the new PDF document. I'm getting a error when trying to create the document.

#### error

```
Uncaught Error: Type of text must be string or Array. "undefined" is not recognized.
    at Object.H.text (/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/pathway_exporter/bower_components/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.html:48)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/pathway_exporter/lib/jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/pathway_exporter/lib/jquery.min.js:3)
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="./bower_components/photon/dist/css/photon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Seremedi - Pathway Exporter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="window">
      <header class="toolbar toolbar-header">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-default" id="open-button">
            <span class="icon icon-folder"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="active btn btn-large btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-download"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="active btn btn-large btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-print"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;"></input>
      </header>
      <div class="window-content">
        <webview id="webview" autosize style="display:inline-flex; width:100%; height:100%"></webview>
      </div>
      <footer class="toolbar toolbar-footer">
        <h1 class="title">&copy; Seremedi - 2017</h1>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $ = require('jquery')
    jsPDF = require('jspdf')
    PDFDocument = require('pdfkit')

    $('#open-button').on('click',function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault();
      $('#file-input').click();
    });
    $('#file-input').on('change',function(evt){
      var location = $('#file-input')[0].files[0].path;
      source = "";
      $('#webview').prop('src', location);
      $.getJSON(location, function(json){
        source = json;
        console.log(source);
      });
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(source.ReferenceId, 10, 10);
      doc.save('file.pdf');
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is displayed by this command you have: "console.log(source);"?

Comment: @TBowman It displays an Object with the attributes from the JSON file

Comment: OK. including the ReferenceId part of the Json, which I assume is an array of strings?

Comment: correct @TBowman

Comment: Shouldn't it be " doc.text(10, 10, source.ReferenceId);" ?

Comment: @TBowman You are right, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. The jsPDF lines simply are executed before `$.getJSON()` finishes. At that point `source` is just an empty string. Thus `source.ReferenceId` is undefined.

```
$.getJSON(location, function(json){
    source = json;
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(source.ReferenceId, 10, 10);
    doc.save('file.pdf');
});
```